# Create a package called hellofrom. Proc_1 should call Proc_2, Proc_2, calls Proc_3;

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

Create a package called hellofrom that contains three public procedures named proc_1, proc_2 and proc_3. Each of these procedures should use DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE() to display the message “Hello from Proc x” where “x” is 1 or 2 or 3, as appropriate.
I had help with this one. Now I'm trying to call Proc 1, 2, 3 to each other.
This is the code I came up with and the mistake is underneath. Not sure what it means.  I added a function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY hellofrom IS
  FUNCTION  call_proc  --private function
   (p_proc_1    VARCHAR2,
    p_proc_2    VARCHAR2,
    p_proc_3    VARCHAR2)
  RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
   BEGIN
    IF p_proc_1 THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Hello from Proc_2');
    ELSEIF p_proc_2 THEN 
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Hello from Proc_3');
    ELSE   
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Hello');
 END IF;
END call_proc;
   PROCEDURE proc_1
   IS
   BEGIN
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Hello from Proc 1');
   END proc_1;

PROCEDURE proc_2
IS
BEGIN
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Hello from Proc 2');
END proc_2;

PROCEDURE  proc_3
IS
BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Hello from Proc 3');
END proc_3;
END hellofrom;
```

Comment: " IF p_proc_1 THEN"  this makes no sense.  p_pfoc_1 is a string, not a boolean, so what is the expected values from your input parameters?

Comment: `elseif` should be `elsif`.

Answer (score 0):

> Now I'm trying to call Proc 1, 2, 3 to each other.

Based on your question heading it means you want to call `proc_2` from `proc_1`, and `proc_3` from `proc_2`;

You don't need a private function with arguments for this. You can write the package code like this.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE hellofrom  -- Create package spec.
AS
PROCEDURE proc_1;
PROCEDURE proc_2;
PROCEDURE proc_3;
END hellofrom;
/


CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY hellofrom IS  

    PROCEDURE proc_1
        IS
    BEGIN
        dbms_output.put_line('Hello from Proc 1');
        proc_2;
    END proc_1;

    PROCEDURE proc_2
        IS
    BEGIN
        dbms_output.put_line('Hello from Proc 2');
        proc_3;
    END proc_2;

    PROCEDURE proc_3
        IS
    BEGIN
        dbms_output.put_line('Hello from Proc 3');
    END proc_3;

END hellofrom;
```

Now call your `proc_1` as follows.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
BEGIN
hellofrom.proc_1;
END;
/
```

**O/p**

```
Hello from Proc 1
Hello from Proc 2
Hello from Proc 3


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Some of my question didn't go through.  Proc_1 should call proc_2 and proc_2 should call proc_3, so you need to include a reference to proc_2 from proc_1, and a reference to proc_3 from proc_2. These need to be visible when I describe the package to check all 3 procedures. That's why I added a function. Doesn't that make it private?

Comment: There are no explicit `private` or `public` definitions for procedures in pl/sql. Those defined in package spec are in public scope. And those defined inside package body are private to package. Now since you want to call one proc from another, there is no need for a function with those arguments. It can be simply a function defined in spec which calls all other procedures. If that is how you want, edit your question giving specific details of how you want to call the function and procedures.